# Azimuth angle limit in Spherical co-ordinate system

Tags: coordinate-systems, polar-coordinates, spherical-coordinates, spherical-geometry

In spherical co-ordinate system $(r, \theta, \phi)$, $\theta$ can range from $0$ to $2\pi$, but $\phi$ only varies from $0$ to $\pi$. Why is that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at a globe. Longitude ranges over 360 degrees, while latitude ranges over 180 degrees. In spherical coordinates, $\theta$ denotes something analogous to longitude (but with an offset domain), and $\phi$ denotes something analogous to latitude (again, with an offset domain: the south pole is "0" and the north pole is "180 degrees", because it's easier to work with positive numbers, I suppose.)

Be warned that there are many spherical polar coord systems, and in some, $\phi$ runs from $-\pi/2$ to $\pi/2,$ and in others, $\phi$ denotes the longitude while $\theta$ denotes latitude. Sigh.

Comment: This second paragraph. Yes. Confused me a great deal at one time. +1

Comment: Continues to confuse me every time I read an engineering paper. :(

Comment: @JohnHughes In the second paragraph, you mentioned that two kinds of polar co-ordinate systems exist that interchange the definition of φ and θ. Do they have different names to differentiate one from the other?

Comment: Alas, no. They're often just called "polar coordinates," and you don't even know whether they're spherical or cylindrical, let along which angle is which, and what domains those angles lie in. Math, Physics, and Engineering all seem to have different conventions, and even within a field there are no strong rules.

Comment: Could be possible to have both angle polar coordinates from -$\pi/2$ to +$\pi/2$, and to have missing points  described by the extension of the sign of $r$ i,e. to have +/- r ?

Comment: @Widawensen: There is certainly a mapping from $(-\pi/2, \pi/2) \times (-\pi/2, \pi/2) \times (-1, 1)$ to $3$-space that's continuous and *almost* a homeomorphism onto the open ball, and you could use those as coordinates (in most places) equally well. I don't recall ever having seen this used in practice, however, but I'm not all that well-read: someone's *probably* done so!